EMFILE: too many open files
I have this error and I can't build my project. My colleagues and I tried many solutions, but we can't find the problem. We need your help T_T
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\\SourceControl\\Ardid\\develop\\ARDID\\ardid-app.next\\server\\next-font-manifest.json' at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:448:20) at Module.\_extensions..json (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1553:22) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:32) at Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:12) at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1297:12) at mod.require (C:\\SourceControl\\Ardid\\develop\\ARDID\\ardid-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\require-hook.js:65:28) at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:123:16) at exportAppImpl (C:\\SourceControl\\Ardid\\develop\\ARDID\\ardid-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\export\\index.js:337:27) at async C:\\SourceControl\\Ardid\\develop\\ARDID\\ardid-app\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\export\\index.js:623:16 { errno: -4066, code: 'EMFILE', syscall: 'open', path: 'C:\\SourceControl\\Ardid\\develop\\ARDID\\ardid-app\\.next\\server\\next-font-manifest.json' }
I tried modified next.config.js with webpack config
node -v 22
next 14

What exactly is the problem? Is it a problem with next, or with node, or with vs-code? What program is throwing this error? :)

Thanks u, I solved the problem, I have rollback commit, and implement again same code, and magic, now build

so you can delete your question, this cannot help others. Thank you

I had the same problem today, but this time I found the real problem. We have a pre-render component with dinamic() ssr:false, and this component has useDateTime. We removed the dynamics and this solves the problem, and we tried other ideas to solve the pre-rendering, but EMPFILE is solved.
